# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore не подключается к MySQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Пытаюсь восстановить сущности из БД MySQL c помощью Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore asp.net core 3.1):

```
Scaffold-Dbcontext -provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -connection "server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; user=root; password=root; database=db_users"
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Keyword not supported: 'port'.

Убираю "port"  из строки:

```
Scaffold-Dbcontext -provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -connection "server=127.0.0.1; user=root; password=root; database=db_users"
```

Выдает ошибку

> ClientConnectionId:7eca0d7a-86db-4074-a287-143f7482ae90 Error
> Number:18456,State:1,Class:14 Ошибка входа пользователя "root".

Логин и пароль верные.

Comment: Порт не используется при подключении к MySQL через EntityFrameworkCore. Под другим пользователем или к другой базе подключается?

Comment: Если Вы подключаетесь к MySQL, то почему у вас провайдер Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer? [Список провайдеров](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) Ваш провайдер: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: @XelaNimed, спасибо, это и было ошибкой. Напишите в ответ, отмечу как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы указываете провайдер для MS SQL сервера `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. В документации к EF Core имеется [список](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) доступных провайдеров. Для подключения к MySql Вы должны установить NuGet пакет провайдера [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) и использовать его. В [GitHub репозитории](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) библиотеки имеется описание основных моментов работы, а также [использование scaffold](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#scaffolding--reverse-engineering):

```
Scaffold-Dbcontext -provider Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -connection "Server=localhost;Database=ef;User=root;Password=123456;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;"
```